# How to find total number of loan by students from last name begin A to D and S? in SQL

Tags: sql

I have tables Loan and borrower. I want to know how many books that have been loaned to students with the initial name starts from A to D and from S only.

I tried this way

```
SELECT COUNT(LNAME)
FROM BORROWER B, LOAN L
WHERE B.CARDNO=L.CARDNO
AND LNAME LIKE 'A%'
AND LNAME LIKE 'B%'
AND LNAME LIKE 'C%'
AND LNAME LIKE 'D%'
AND LNAME LIKE 'S%'
GROUP BY LNAME;
```

I tried that way and resulted nothing.
can anyone help?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you use `AND` instead of `OR` for the name.

```
SELECT LNAME, COUNT(LNAME) 
FROM BORROWER B, LOAN L 
WHERE B.CARDNO=L.CARDNO 
AND (LNAME LIKE 'A%' OR LNAME LIKE 'B%' OR LNAME LIKE 'C%' OR LNAME LIKE 'D%' OR LNAME LIKE 'S%')
GROUP BY LNAME;
```

Comment: well that work. however it does not display the last name. so, can it be shown as the last name and followed by the total book loaned?

Comment: so, how do i select that?
what is the additional code?

Comment: @AgusMaloco seriously?? it seems that the above code is not your code.. I already updated my answer, `SELECT LNAME`..

Comment: thank you, i just see that and  have changed that.
it works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 SELECT COUNT(LNAME) 
    FROM BORROWER B, LOAN L 
    WHERE B.CARDNO=L.CARDNO
    GROUP BY LNAME having (LNAME LIKE 'A%' OR LNAME LIKE 'B%' OR LNAME LIKE 'C%' OR LNAME LIKE 'D%' OR LNAME LIKE 'S%');
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(LNAME) 
    FROM BORROWER B, LOAN L 
    WHERE B.CARDNO=L.CARDNO
    GROUP BY LNAME having (LNAME LIKE 'A%' OR LNAME LIKE 'B%' OR LNAME LIKE 'C%' OR LNAME LIKE 'D%' OR LNAME LIKE 'S%');

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended NOT to use Non-ANSI joins if you are working on MS SQL Server. Some of these have already been deprecated in recent versions of SQL Server. You can also try the code below for your question:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(LNAME)
FROM 
    BORROWER B
    INNER JOIN LOAN L ON B.CARDNO=L.CARDNO
WHERE 
    LNAME LIKE '[A-D,S]%'
GROUP BY LNAME;
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL (LIKE doesn't support "regular expressions")

Comment: That's not correct. It is very much standard SQL - [MSDN Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: T-SQL is **not** "standard SQL"